# How to add multiple records to gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have created some textboxes and a button. When pressing the button I want to display every new record in the gridview, but have only made if work, to add a record and then when you add it again the old one disapears and new one show up.

```
var dt = new DataTable();

        DataColumn cl = new DataColumn("From");
        dt.Columns.Add(cl);
        cl = new DataColumn("To");
        dt.Columns.Add(cl);

        DataColumn cl1 = new DataColumn("Area");
        dt.Columns.Add(cl1);
        cl1 = new DataColumn("Sector");
        dt.Columns.Add(cl1);

        DataColumn cl2 = new DataColumn("CompanyName");
        dt.Columns.Add(cl2);
        cl2 = new DataColumn("Description");
        dt.Columns.Add(cl2);

        DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
        dr[0] = TextBoxFrom.Text;
        dr[1] = TextBoxTo.Text;
        dr[2] = TextBoxArea.Text;
        dr[3] = TextBoxSector.Text;
        dr[4] = TextBoxCompanyName.Text;
        dr[5] = TextBoxDescription.Text;
        dt.Rows.Add(dr);


        GridViewAllAssigments.DataSource = dt;
        GridViewAllAssigments.DataBind();
```

Answer (score 2):

First of all, I suggest you don't using `DataTable` to bind the GridView, create instead a class to hold your data.

```
public class MyData
{
    public string From { get; set; }
    public string To { get; set; }
    public string Area { get; set; }
    public string Sector { get; set; }
    public string CompanyName { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

You'll have to maintain the data in a Session variable, so you don't lose you data every postback:

```
public List<MyData> MyData
{
    get
    {
        if (Session["MyData"] == null)
            return new List<MyData>();

        return (List<MyData>)Session["MyData"];
    }
    set
    {
        Session["MyData"] = value;
    }
}
```

When retrieving the value from the controls, use the following:

```
var myData = this.MyData;
myData.Add(new MyData() { 
        Area = TextBoxArea.Text, 
        CompanyName = TextBoxCompanyName.Text, 
        Description = TextBoxDescription.Text, 
        From = TextBoxFrom.Text, 
        Sector = TextBoxSector.Text, 
        To = TextBoxTo.Text 
    });

this.MyData = myData;           

GridViewAllAssigments.DataSource = this.MyData;
GridViewAllAssigments.DataBind();
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code doesn't work because you are creating a new instance of a DataTable every time and then adding the new row.

For this to work, you need to create the DataTable **once**, add the row to the existing DataTable and rebind it.

Something like this:

```
DataTable dt = Session["DT"]  as DataTable;
if(dt==null)
{
   dt = new DataTable(); 
   Session["DT"]=dt;//store it for next round trip
}

//rest of your code code to add a new row...

GridViewAllAssigments.DataSource = dt;
GridViewAllAssigments.DataBind();
```